# Is there a way to transfer apps, watch faces, settings from Samsung Galaxy Watch4 to Watch6?

Tags: samsung, data-transfer, smartwatch

I just purchased the Samsung Galaxy Watch6.  Is there a way to transfer apps, faces, and settings over from Galaxy Watch4?

Answer (score 3):

Finally took a punt at it.

- Open `Galaxy Wearable` App
- Click on hamburger menu at top left
- Select `Add new device`
- If you dont have a backup on the old watch, make one.  (I had automatic backups, but made another anyway)
- Add the new watch, and along the way it asks if you want to restore the backup
- It tells you what it is able to restore and then restores it.

So, it didnt restore apps and watch faces, "because they are not compatible due to different OS".  It just restored the settings.